# I am writing a madlib in php, saving it to a db using mysql, then trying to pull out each new story in descending order

Tags: php, mysql

I am not sure how to get the story out of the db, I am getting this error:

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   string given in /home/ubuntu/workspace/projects/project_1/madlib.php
>   on line 33 Call Stack: 0.0009 248160 1. {main}()
>   /home/ubuntu/workspace/projects/project_1/madlib.php:0 0.0058 257240
>   2. mysqli_fetch_array() /home/ubuntu/workspace/projects/project_1/madlib.php:33

```
<?php
//connecting to the db
$dbc = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'project1')
        or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');

//creating variables       
$noun = $_POST['noun']; 
$verb = $_POST['verb'];
$adjective = $_POST['adjective'];
$body_part = $_POST['bodypart'];
$food_item = $_POST['fooditem'];
$full_story = "Here are some things to do at recess." 
              "Start a game of touch $body_part-ball." 
              "Put a $noun in someones lunch." 
              "Start a $food_item fight in the school $adjective room." 
              "Choose sides and have a $verb ball tournament.";

//inserting form info into db
$query = "INSERT INTO my_game (noun, verb, adjective, body_part, food_item) " .
  "VALUES ('$noun', '$verb', '$adjective', '$body_part', '$food_item')";

 //get query result from db  
$result = mysqli_query($dbc, $query)
        or die('Error querying database.');

if(empty($noun) || empty($verb) || empty($adjective) || empty($body_part) || empty($food_item)) {
  echo "You have not filled in all of the fields.Please go back and try again.";
}

$query2 = "SELECT * FROM my_game WHERE id ORDER BY desc";

  //while loop grabs name from array       
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query2)) {
    $noun = $row['noun'];
    $verb = $row['verb'];
    $adjective = $row['adjective'];
    $body_part = $row['body_part'];
    $food_item = $row['food_item'];    
    $full_story = "Here are some things to do at recess." 
                  "Start a game of touch $body_part-ball." 
                  "Put a $noun in someones lunch." 
                  "Start a $food_item fight in the school $adjective room." 
                  "Choose sides and have a $verb ball tournament.";

    //outputs story       
    echo $full_story;

}

//close connection 
mysqli_close($dbc);

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not executing the query before trying to fetch. The query is just a string in `$query2`.

You need to execute the query by calling [mysqli->query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

Since you already did this above it looks like you just missed it all together on the second query by accident. ( I've done this before).

After this line

```
$query2 = "SELECT * FROM my_game WHERE id ORDER BY desc";
```

You can do something like

```
 //get query result from db  
$result2 = mysqli_query($dbc, $query2)
        or die('Error querying database.');
```

and change this accordingly

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
```

Comment: Thanks Jesse, I made those changes and I am getting further but I now get an Error Querying database. I checked my table and it is inserting the user data into the table, but its the query2 where it dies. My sql skills are a little rusty, can i order by descending using the query i wrote or am i missing something?

Comment: it was my mysql statement, got it fixed! thanks for your help!

Comment: If you have received an answer that you accept. Please be sure to accept the answer by clicking the green checkbox under the arrows to the left of my answer. This allows future visitors to see your question is complete.